# Get default line color cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I noticed when you plot that the first line is blue, then orange, then green, and so on.

Is there some way to access this list of colors?  I've seen a million posts on how to change the color cycle or access the iterator, but not on how to just get the list of colors that matplotlib cycles through by default.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

In matplotlib versions >= 1.5, you can print the `rcParam` called `axes.prop_cycle`:

```
print(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'])

# [u'#1f77b4', u'#ff7f0e', u'#2ca02c', u'#d62728', u'#9467bd', u'#8c564b', u'#e377c2', u'#7f7f7f', u'#bcbd22', u'#17becf']
```

Or equivalently, in `python2`:

```
print plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
```

In versions < 1.5, this was called `color_cycle`:

```
print plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']

# [u'b', u'g', u'r', u'c', u'm', u'y', u'k']
```

Note that the default color cycle changed in version 2.0.0 http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-in-default-property-cycle

Comment: Thanks!  Slight correction: The first one should be: `lines_colour_cycle = [p['color'] for p in plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']]`

Comment: @Peter, yes, or `plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']`

Answer (score 192):

Often, there is no need to get the default color cycle from anywhere, as it is the default one, so just using it is sufficient.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

t = np.arange(5)

for i in range(4):
    line, = ax.plot(t,i*(t+1), linestyle = '-')
    ax.plot(t,i*(t+1)+.3,color = line.get_color(), linestyle = ':')

plt.show()
```

[image]

In case you want to *use* the default color cycle for something different, there are of course several options.

#### "tab10" colormap

First it should be mentionned that the `"tab10"` colormap comprises the colors from the default color cycle, you can get it via `cmap = plt.get_cmap("tab10")`.

Equivalent to the above would hence be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

t = np.arange(5)
cmap = plt.get_cmap("tab10")
for i in range(4):
    ax.plot(t,i*(t+1),   color=cmap(i), linestyle = '-')
    ax.plot(t,i*(t+1)+.3,color=cmap(i), linestyle = ':')

plt.show()
```

#### Colors from color cycle

You can also use the color cycler directly, `cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']`. This gives list with the colors from the cycle, which you can use to iterate over.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

t = np.arange(5)
cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

for i in range(4):
    ax.plot(t,i*(t+1),   color=cycle[i], linestyle = '-')
    ax.plot(t,i*(t+1)+.3,color=cycle[i], linestyle = ':')

plt.show()
```

#### The `CN` notation

Finally, the `CN` notation allows to get the `N`th color of the color cycle, `color="C{}".format(i)`. This however only works for the first 10 colors (`N in [0,1,...9]`)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

t = np.arange(5)

for i in range(4):
    ax.plot(t,i*(t+1),   color="C{}".format(i), linestyle = '-')
    ax.plot(t,i*(t+1)+.3,color="C{}".format(i), linestyle = ':')

plt.show()
```

All codes presented here produce the same plot.

Comment: is it possible to tell matplotlib to use some kind of cycle? Having to iterate over the colors array means you have to add the logic for going back to index 0 after using one full cycle.

Comment: @Mehdi Sure, matplotlib does use a color cycle. This question asks for getting the colors of this cycle.

Comment: I think `CN` notation should be much more prominent in your answer, I almost missed it. I suspect the vast majority of use cases is happy with being able to access only the first 10 colours, and passing `'C1'` an friends is way less boilerplate than explicitly grabbing the prop cycle.

Comment: upvoted for the `CN`-notation, it was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Ah thank you for the `CN` notation! Exactly what I needed without bothering to actually get a handle of the default colour cycle.

Answer (score 8):

### The CN notation revisited

I'd like to address a new development of Matplotlib.  In a previous answer we read

> Finally, the `CN` notation allows to get the `N`th color of the color cycle, `color="C{}".format(i)`. This however only works for the first 10 colors (`N in [0,1,...9]`)

but

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

t = np.linspace(0,6.28, 629)                                                      
for N in (1, 2): 
    C0N, C1N = 'C%d'%(N), 'C%d'%(N+10) 
    plt.plot(t, N*np.sin(t), c=C0N, ls='-',  label='c='+C0N) 
    plt.plot(t, N*np.cos(t), c=C1N, ls='--', label='c='+C1N) 
plt.legend() ; plt.grid() ; plt.show()
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Could you add a link to the source? Thanks

Comment: @Luca I have no source, I just have found that it works...  At any rate, the ultimate source is Matplotlib source code, but `.../matplotlib/colors.py` is > 2000 lines and alas I haven't found my way in it when looking to answer your question.

Comment: You just show a plot and leave people to make up their own conclusions. What's the point in that?

Comment: For those that are interested, this change was made in v3.1.0, and is documented in the API changes [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.1.0.html#cn-colors-now-support-n-10)

Answer (score 5):

if you're looking for a quick one-liner to get the RGB colors that matplotlib uses for its lines, here it is:

```
>>> import matplotlib; print('\n'.join([str(matplotlib.colors.to_rgb(c)) for c in matplotlib.pyplot.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']]))
(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765)
(1.0, 0.4980392156862745, 0.054901960784313725)
(0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313)
(0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392)
(0.5803921568627451, 0.403921568627451, 0.7411764705882353)
(0.5490196078431373, 0.33725490196078434, 0.29411764705882354)
(0.8901960784313725, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7607843137254902)
(0.4980392156862745, 0.4980392156862745, 0.4980392156862745)
(0.7372549019607844, 0.7411764705882353, 0.13333333333333333)
(0.09019607843137255, 0.7450980392156863, 0.8117647058823529)
```

Or for uint8:

```
import matplotlib; print('\n'.join([str(tuple(int(round(v*255)) for v in matplotlib.colors.to_rgb(c))) for c in matplotlib.pyplot.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']]))
(31, 119, 180)
(255, 127, 14)
(44, 160, 44)
(214, 39, 40)
(148, 103, 189)
(140, 86, 75)
(227, 119, 194)
(127, 127, 127)
(188, 189, 34)
(23, 190, 207)
```