# How can I get the standard colors used in pandas dataframe or series plot?

Tags: python, pandas, colors

Pandas plot with multiple graphs has this standard colors (the first four colors are shown here):

[image]

How can I get programmatically these four colors and the following ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to `category10` color palette:

[image]

Programmatically you can access them through:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
```

```
['#1f77b4',
 '#ff7f0e',
 '#2ca02c',
 '#d62728',
 '#9467bd',
 '#8c564b',
 '#e377c2',
 '#7f7f7f',
 '#bcbd22',
 '#17becf']
```

See [this page of the `matplotlib` docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/dflt_style_changes.html) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086276/get-default-line-colour-cycle) for more info.